# C# Code Snipped

Tags: c#

Is there any control for auto complate my code in textbox at runtime?

There is a textbox in my form and  when i want to write c# code at runtime.Can it be auto complete code in textbox?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Can you confirm that you are trying to write a windows form application that accepts C# code in a textbox and you want to provide intellisense?  If so, that is a decidedly non-trivial request.

Comment: I will run my application after I will write textbox in form and complete the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out [Actipro SyntaxEditor](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/dotnet/windowsforms/syntaxeditor/default.aspx) and [Quantum Whale Editor.NET](http://www.qwhale.net/products/editor.htm). Both controls support C# editing with syntax highlighting and "intellisense" drop-downs.

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms, the standard combo box control includes options for providing the auto-complete mechanism based on the items in the drop down list.

I am assuming, of course, that you are not trying to do something like Intellisense. Your question is not clear.